# In jenkins, how to re-run old builds of a job?

Tags: jenkins

Some old builds are failed in my jenkins job and I need to re-run them again. How to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by republish? Do you mean, re-run the job?

Comment: yes  i need to re-run the job

Answer (score 7):

If the job is a jenkins pipeline, open the failed build and select the `Replay` option. Otherwise select the `Rebuild` option.

*Sample Replay Option*:
[image: Replay Option for Jenkins pipeline job]

*Sample Rebuild Option*:
[image: Rebuild Option for Jenkins non-pipeline jobs]

Comment: Note that this seems to imply the use of the Rebuilder plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/)